# Using aux splitter, can I turn one stereo output into one mono left, and the other output into a mono right?

Tags: audio, speakers, system-sounds

Apologies if the question seems obscure.
I have a splitter for my laptop that leads to two 3.5mm female jacks. Id like to plug a speaker in, and my headphones; and have for example my speaker have exclusively left, and my headphones have exclusively right.

For context, I just bought some pioneer ddj200 decks, and they’re a bit obscure in the sense that they just have a usb. Most DJ decks have an external audio port for headphones. This just comes with a splitter. When using rekordbox and using a splitter, the alternative outputs use left and right. I don’t think my laptop is isolating the audio channels correctly, so gets some overlay. This could be down to my laptops sound card possibly not having enough channels, I’m not really sure.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, that should work just fine: The audio hardware has different DACs for each channel, and nothing stops you from using it as two mono outputs. You can even configure it (how depends on your OS) to show up as two mono outputs in the audio settings.

If you hear overlay, it's definitely not related to not having enough channels; though it could be poor hardware design that leads to crosstalk, or the way you have set it up on your OS.

Comment: How do I set this up? I’ve looked a lot on google and can’t really find anything. Should it just happen by default?

Comment: You could start by telling us your OS ...

Comment: Sorry yeah I’m on Windows 8.1, god knows why just forgot to update laptop in time for 10. I feel like upon research it should work just right away. Cheers